# Pop up problems with scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is what i'm trying to create [CodePen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LHFaB)

The idea is that the popup should work exactly like the Pinterest [Link](http://www.pinterest.com)

The problems i have are:

- When u close the pop-up, the page always jumps to the top. It should stay where it was
- The popup is fixed, how can i make it that you can move it like on Pinterest? I would like to have some spacing on the top and when u scroll u actually move the up
- If u have any chance to view this on mobile, please do. I want to make the site responsive. If u view the pop-up in the mobile version, it isn't smooth. That means when u scroll and move you finger from the touch screen, the scroll stops immediately. So it feels like you need to push the content down with you finger. It doesn't flow so u could swipe and it would stop slowly

I try to figure this out for days already and can't get it. Any help is welcome :) tnx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using anchor tag for the close button like this :

```
<div class="close"><a href="#portfolio">close</a></div>
```

Do this instead :

```
<span class="close">Close</span>
```

Don't forget to add `cursor:pointer` style for `.close` class.

Your problem will be solved.

Right now, the image that triggers popup disappears when you click close button on firefox just in case if you haven't checked on it yet. So, better not use anchor tag for the close button. My suggestion would be Never use anchor tag for close button.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That helped to solve the first part! Thnx! I will remember this in the future.

Comment: Oh! I forgot other parts. Would love to give you solutions for them too. Can you update your second point and make it little more clear?

Comment: I did actually found the solution here: http://jsfiddle.net/WzA4y/140/ but the problem is, it doesn't work for me in safari.

Comment: It's working perfectly on my Safari. By problem, what exactly you mean?

Comment: Yea i just also saw it. Sry about that. I'm trying to add the code to my site i'm doing and there is some issue.

Comment: I work a bit more on it and saw that the problem i have is on my page. I have a only one long scrollable page and the first section in this page is a 100% width an height background image with logo in the middle. It seems like that one is messing up the pop-up. Always. Should i provide u with code.

Comment: Yes. Please provide the code or may be the link where you are working if it's online.

Comment: If u can make it work it.. than u are the king!  here is the link: http://www.dejan-markovic.com/test/     and it should look like Pinterest popup... and when u close the popup, you are there where u start it..

Comment: @DeanDeey You are missing few things. That's why the problems happening. Add these CSS styles: 
`.body-locked {overflow: hidden;}`
Give just 80% width for your `.modal` class so that it doesn't cover the whole page. Right now, it's 100%
And lastly, add this style for `.close-modal` class so that that close buttons sticks on top just like on pinterest.
`.close-modal { position: fixed; top: 0;}` Let me know if you don't understand and need more clarification.

Comment: Tnx. I get it. But the biggest problem I see is that when u click on the modal, the scroll of the website should control the modal. But it doesn't, because when the model open's another scroll appears, so actually i have on the side two scroll bars then. That's the biggest problem.

Comment: That's why you need to add this style `.body-locked {overflow: hidden;}` which you have missed. And it's the reason you are seeing two scrolls.

Comment: I see yes.. but still, when i scroll the modal, i'm also scrolling the website in the background.

Comment: I will do one thing. I will provide you a link for your style.css file. You just replace your css with mine. Upload it on your server and check.

Comment: Here's the link. Please copy all the css and replace yours with this one. Then check. http://pastebin.com/6hrPFEwY

Comment: look: http://www.dejan-markovic.com/test/  and it is with your CSS: http://www.dejan-markovic.com/test/css/style.css

Comment: It's weird actually.. but anyway, don't bother anymore with it :) i do really appreciate your help, but yea, it doesn't go anyway with those problems, so i'll try find another easier solution :)

Comment: Oh and the actually result was meant to be that at the end: http://oi41.tinypic.com/286sv1d.jpg

Comment: I think i just found a solution.. When we are calling the .body-close in query i added this code .body-locked {overflow: hidden;position: fixed; overflow-y:scroll}

Comment: The only problem is now, that i want to make the background around the pop-up transparent and it keeps jumping back to the top, right after u click on modal.

Comment: The problem is there's too many unnecessary code in your html and css files. And you are still not implementing that modal in a correct way. Don't go searching for other solutions. It's the perfect solution for you. You just need to clean up the unnecessary parts. Wait for tomorrow. I will clean up and send you working code.